# library for sorting vector of string

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I have some data stored in vector ;

```
       vector<string> data ;
```

I want to **sort** strings in data, **alphabetically**.Are there any sorting algorithm or complex library which you can recommend me?

Ex ;

```
assume in data ;
              aaaa
              ccc
              bbb
              acb

after sorting, data ;
              aaaa
              acb
              bbb
              ccc
```

Comment: What is `Vector`?  Did you write it yourself?  Did you mean `vector` (lowercase) from the STL?  It's hard to know how to help you without more details about this type.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you explicitly be asking for a *complex library* to solve a simple problem?

Comment: @Space_COcbOy, because I will use it with more complex problem.Also, for some easy part of the problem,I will use basic "standart library  sort function"  to get rid of efficiency problem .( Now I have searching all of the sorting algorithm before starting to write program. )

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::sort` and forget about the issue until you recognize it as a problem? Note that your set of requirements might be ill-defined, if you demonstrate that you do need something faster than `std::sort`, then you most probably don't want to use a `std::vector` (BTW, if you prepend standard types with `std::` in questions, it will be clear that you refer to `std::vector` and not `homebrew::vector`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are aiming for efficiency even before starting to write a program, do it other way around : first write a **correct** program, then profile it and optimize bottlenecks.

Therefore, I can only recommend what other already did : [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Answer (score 8):

The Standard library's `<algorithm>` header has a `sort` function you can use, see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 1):

Normal `std::sort` should do the job for you, see [this snippet on ideone](http://ideone.com/lNo7B).

Answer (score 0):

You can use trie trees http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie